# Jenkins Build Error using Git

Tags: jenkins

I get the below error when running build via jenkins

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from https://my.server.com/repo.git

FATAL: Unable to call fetch2. Invalid object ID 10
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to call fetch2. Invalid object ID 10
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:269)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from https://my.server.come/repo1.git
FATAL: Unable to call fetch2. Invalid object ID 10
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to call fetch2. Invalid object ID 10
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:269)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Help is much appreciated.